# How do you use ggplot2 to create boxplots when the groupings overlap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data which has an output variable and a set of labels. The problem that I'm facing is that the labels are not mutually exclusive. For example, lets say that I am analyzing paintings and I am looking at the price of the painting and the colors used to create it. I would have a dataset that looks like this:

| Price | Colors Used |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Red, Black, Blue |
| 12.5 | Red, Green, Yellow, Black, purple |
| 11 | Blue, White |
| 15 | Red |

I want to use ggplot2 to create a boxplot of price for all the rows that include "red" in the colors used, and then do the same for "Purple", "Black", etc. etc. But the problem that I run into is that GGplot2 treats each of these labels as unique if I simply write

```
ggplot(aes(x=colors, y=price))+
geom_boxplot()
```

Does anyone know of a good workaround to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate_rows()` to prepare your data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

your_data %>%
  separate_rows(Colors.Used) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(x = Colors.Used, y = Price))
```

Result:

[image: Result with separate_rows()]

Data used:

```
your_data <- tibble::tribble( ~Price, ~Colors.Used, 10, "Red, Black, Blue", 12.5, "Red, Green, Yellow, Black, purple", 11, "Blue, White", 15, "Red")
```